# How to import components in separate components, but simultaneously importing them only once in the build size?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js, apexcharts

I am using `vue-apexchart` and I am importing them in my components, not directly in my main.js file. But importing them separately imports the whole 437Kb in each of my components. How should I handle this such that the build is only included in one of the bundle only, but I am able to use it in my components.

Comment: Did you notice that after running `vue-cli-service build --report` ? That you have multiple ApexCharts in the bundle ?

Comment: I found out by using webpack bundle analyzer

Comment: If you are lazy-loading your routes (or some of the components) - Webpack will include all the code that is needed to run the given lazy loaded chunk. You will need to play with `config.optimization` inside the `configureWebpack` method in `vue.config.js`